# how to check for object that record type is enable for object or not in apex code

Tags: apex

I have to check for standard object that it is having any record type or not instead of system generated record type(master record type).
Without doing any query on record type while doing query on record type it shows dependency in package.

Answer (score 1):

A code similar to below will return number of record types for a object:

```
Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().size()
```

So you can have a check based on number returned by above code.

Comment: This query also returns at least one record type "Master", which is generated by system.

Comment: Yes. So if it returns one there are no record types else there are record types available..